# process.start() method is not producing files

Tags: c#

I have an .exe file. I want to run the .exe file with `Process.Start()` command. The .exe file produces two files when executed one is .xls file and another one is .htm file. When I run the .exe file through .net code, the two files that are supposed to be produced are not produced. Below is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process.Start(@"C:\Test\test.exe");
}
```

I am not sure if the process is getting executed, but I don't see any error. Also, I don't see any files produced. If I manually run the process then I can see the two files produced in the same folder where the .exe file resides.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you wrap the line with try catch and see if any exception happens?

Comment: If you just double click the exe in Windows Explorer, what happens? Does it generate your files? If not, I wouldn't expect calling Process.Start to be any different.

Comment: *"I can see the two files produced in the same folder where the .exe file resides".* How does Test.exe determine where to create the files? If it's based on some current directory, then it's possible they are being created in your bin folder instead of where the executable resides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try waiting for the process to finish:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Test\test.exe").WaitForExit();
```

Better for debugging:

```
Process process = Process.Start(@"C:\Test\test.exe");
int id = process.Id;
Process runningProc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
runningProc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Why do you do the extra step of `Process.GetProcessById(id);`, why not just `process.WaitForExit()`?

Comment: `Process.GetProcessById(id);` trows an exception if the id is not found. This allows you to check if the process is actual running.

Comment: if you had a id via `process.Id` that means it was running at some point. You don't get a id if the program is not running.

Comment: Thank You. That solved two of  my issues. I was trying to copy the file to shred drive after it was produced. WaitforExit solved that issue. Thank You again

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if you put a breakpoint in this line `int id = process.Id;` or insert a `Thread.Sleep(x);` after it you can wait a specific time an check if it's still running.